# Implementing site version for disabled

Tags: css

I have very huge project. I have to implement dynamic font changing (version for disabled etc.). So I have many css files with classes where there are declared font-sizes. Now I have to do 2 another files where will be defined normal fonts and bigger fonts. Something like:

```
fontSize8 {
  font-size: 8px;
}

fontSize9 {
 font-size: 9px;
}
```

etc.

And in second file:

```
fontSize8 {
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

etc.

Fonts everywhere in the project have to depend on predefined classes in this files. My question: somewhere in the css files I have something like this:

```
DIV.LabelText {
    font-size: 12;
}
```

How can I relate this two classes (`fontSize12` and `DIV.LabelText`) not to change every usage of class `DIV.LabelText` in doc files? It would be a disaster if I have to correct every case of usage.

Comment: use `SASS` http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can do this in pure CSS. Javascript could adjust the CSS for you after page load. But I must say: it seems a bit odd to have classes devoted just to setting font size to specific pixel values. That really defeats the purpose of using style sheets to define styles by class.

Comment: You could do things slightly differently with `em`. [Like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4L78m/1/) where you just need to change the percentage `font-size` on `body` in order to increase/decrease all `em` font sizes.

Comment: I'am not designer so i can do nothing with this :).

Comment: @misterManSam it would be very elegant, but i'am not decision-making person in this project. By the way thanks for tip.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean when you say "How can I relate this two classes (fontSize12 and DIV.LabelText) not to change every usage of class DIV.LabelText in doc files? " Do you want Div.LabelText styling to be always applied or fontSize12 styling to be always applied.

Comment: @Godwin Something like
  DIV.LabelText {
      fontSize12;
  }
But i know that inheritance in css is not possible in stricte way.

Comment: I have answerd based on your input, you can enforce inheritance using the !important attribute. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

To override or strictly implement a styling over styling at different level of granularity , you can use this attribute

```
!important
```

An example

```
fontSize8 {
  font-size: 8px !important;
}
```

This will override other styling even , inline stylings if any. The priority of styling as in ascending order is given below :

Style sheets can have a few different sources:

- User agent:
     -- For example, the browser’s default style sheet.
- User
     -- Such as the user’s browser options.
- Author
     -- This is the CSS provided by the page (whether inline, embedded or external)

Knowing this, let’s look at the final order, in ascending order of importance:

- User agent declarations,
- User declarations,
- Author declarations,
- Author !important declarations,
- User !important declarations.

This information can be found [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/)

Comment: And what if something below in doc hierarchy will have also !important attribute? This is rhetorical question I guess. But thanks for replay. It will trick most of cases.

Comment: If a child has !important , then it takes priority. i guess then u have to resort to manual updates of these specific child elements or use Javascript to handle it. Hope this helps .

Comment: As i wrote it's not full answer.

Comment: Ok thats your call , no probs .